# Adding a tooltip to CMenu item(s)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, tooltip, cmenu

A while ago, I have tried to add a tooltip for testing purposes on a CMenu item. Now I would need it, and I'm facing the same issue again.

This question and answer(s):
[MFC : How to add tooltip in Cmenu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400180/mfc-how-to-add-tooltip-in-cmenu-items)

doesn't help me at all, as this "newline magic" is simply not working.

Also, it seems like I'm not the only one having problems with it:
[MFC CMenu tooltip not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610691/mfc-cmenu-tooltip-not-being-displayed)

```
void CTextListCtrl::CreateMenu(void)
{
    m_Menu.CreateMenu();
    CMenu submenu;
    submenu.CreatePopupMenu();
    submenu.AppendMenuW(MF_STRING, IDC_RESEND_POPUP, L"&Resend\nShow me the tooltip");
    //Other menu items...
    m_Menu.AppendMenuW(MF_POPUP, reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(submenu.m_hMenu), L"");
    submenu.Detach();
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

However, increasing the letters of the text results in a bigger pop-up menu, not a menu tooltip.

*I have seen the other links in this answer, and checked them and the projects. But these are not what I want.*

Does someone know what I did wrong, or is there another solution/source which could be helpful ?

---

Edit: As I have mentioned before in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558880/adding-a-tooltip-to-cmenu-items#comment51995499_32046766), here is a [sample solution](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07597732216098941519) with minimum requirements to reproduce the problem. *(See `CMenuListCtrl.cpp(100)`)*
*Tested with VS2010 & VS2015 (same result).*

Comment: maybe its just about replacing \n by \r\n which is expected by MFC for line breaks.

Comment: @Totonga No, I tried this, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's trick that will fix your problem, "newline magic" will work for sure.

Ensure that you are using version 6 of ComCtl32.dll.

Add below block in stdafx.h file and rebuild your project.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32'\
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

[image]

Comment: This is in `stdafx.h` by default and it does not work.

Comment: Can you share with me your VC++ solution?

Comment: [Solution uploaded](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07597732216098941519) with minimum requirements to reproduce the problem. Assume `CMenu` can be in any other class or control too.

Comment: visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/217588/Porting-a-legacy-MFC-app-to-MFC-Feature-Pack, sample includes CMenuToolTip class, See how it is used. See OnMenuSelect()

Comment: This is for a document based MFC application and I have seen this easier done in the Microsoft samples before. However, this is a dialog based application. There's just a plain `CMenu` and submenu(s). The `CMenu` can either be a system-menu as in your screenshot, or a pop-up on a `CListCtrl`, `CComboBox` or on an other control. I have also seen and checked [the project with a similar dialog](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tooltipcontrols/article.php/c5233/Tooltips-for-Menu-Items-and-Popup-Menu-Items.htm) - the delivered `.exe` in the project works. Compiling it does not. (no TT)